# Prevent deletion of parent if child record present

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a category table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this is how it displays categories with subcategories after being run

[image]

I need to Prevent deletion of parent record if it has one or couple of child records. How do i do it?.

Comment: Why not a foreign key ?

Comment: @berty, where do I add the foreign key?

Answer (score 5):

You could have a self-referential foreign key, but you have to create it in two stages:

```
create table foo (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    parent int default null
);

alter table foo add foreign key (parent) references foo (id)
    on delete restrict;
```

You have to do it as a separate `alter`, because it won't work within the table definition itself - the table doesn't exist at that point, so the FK verification will fail and not allow the table to be created.

Comment: thank you, that was the word i was looking for, "self-referential foreign key" . I wasn't sure if I could define a self-referential foreign key. Let me try.